# differences between reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions and openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-authentication

As of Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1, Facebook split `openActiveSessionWithPermissions` to 2 parts:
openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions and openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions (explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/)).

However, Facebook's documentation says to call `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` first, 
then call `reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions`. I don't see any explanation on when I should use `openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions`.

Please help me understand the difference between 2 methods and when I should use them.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible scenarios:

1. The user if coming to your app for the first time and has never authorized your app.
2. The user is returning to your app and has previously authorized your app. A cached token is available so that the session can be opened. The cached token also stores previous permissions granted.

In case (1) you can only open a session for read permissions. You cannot ask for publish permissions the first time.

In case (2), you may ask for publish permissions. You would have to check if there was cached token.

In either cases (1) or (2) you could always call the reauthorize methods after the session has been initially opened.

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 approaches you can follow:

- A. You can ask users for permissions for publish actions when they connect to facebook and authorize your app for the first time.

In this case you would need to use *reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions*:..

- B. The alternative is to ask for permissions when they want to perform a specific publish action.

In this case you would need to use *reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions* first and later *reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions*

IMHO the first approach is more seamless, but might end up leading to bad results, since some users don't want to give permissions at the very first time they authorize an app. The second approach requires more interaction from the user, but gives them more control.

Facebook recommends the second approach, but it is actually your choice.

Cheers

Comment: You can't request publish permissions at the first time you open a session, you must request a basic read permission and then reauth for more permissions.

Comment: @Maurizio that statement is no longer true